# nsstring to nsmutable array

Tags: nsmutablearray

I'm making an app in which i want to access the contact's first name and store them in to nsmutable array so that i can get the values of that array like `array[0]` up to `array[i-1]` and print them in table view.Here is my code:

```
CFErrorRef error = NULL;

ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &error);

if (addressBook != nil)
{
    contacts_Image_List=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSLog(@"Succesful.");

    NSArray *allContacts = (__bridge_transfer NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);




    NSUInteger i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < [allContacts count]; i++)
    {
Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];



        ABRecordRef contactPerson = (__bridge ABRecordRef)allContacts[i];

        NSString *firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
        NSString *lastName =  (__bridge_transfer NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
        NSString *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];

        person.firstName = firstName;
        person.lastName = lastName;
        person.fullName = fullName;

       // person.userThumb[i]=firstName;

       //[person.userThumb[i] addObject:@"firstName"];

       //above line gives null

        NSLog(@"%@",person.userThumb[i]);
```

my mutable array is in `Person.h` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each iteration just do:

```
[person.yourMutableArray addObject:fullName]
```

Just ensure that your MutableArray has already been allocated, and that you only allocate it once.